# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'eligibleURLPatterns' of 'Yt' as it is null

Tags: javascript

each time that i run live sever i got this error in my console:

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'eligibleURLPatterns' of 'Yt' as it is null.

image of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql91y.png

Comment: We can't possibly help if you don't add some code/data to your question as a [mcve]. There simply isn't enough information here.

Comment: i do not have any code, i just have html and js file that linked to html

Comment: OK, well it appears to be an issue with `companion-bubble.js`. You should contact whoever wrote that. It seems to be related to a chrome extension?

Comment: nobody wrote that file and i dont khow what is companion-bubble.js is. i dont have this error sicne last two days and i don not install any extension on chrome

Comment: Well, it's being called in somewhere, so you might have to do some more debugging.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I started seeing this error too and it seems is from the Loom chrome extension. You can verify by going into the network tab and searching for `companion-bubble.js`.

[image]

This would show you the extension id, which you can inspect using a similar link: chrome://extensions/?id=extensionid

Comment: Had the same isssue. Disabling the Loom extension worked for me.

Comment: yes, it solves my problem

Answer (score 10):

Removing the Loom extension and adding it again seems to solve the issue for me.

[Loom Chrome Extension Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loom-%E2%80%93-free-screen-record/liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb)

Answer (score 2):

Error can also be, So it is nothing but error from loom extension as @andres said

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'eligibleURLPatterns' of 'Jt' as it is null.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable/remove [Loom chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loom-%E2%80%93-free-screen-record/liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb) and the error will disapppear

Comment: This seems like a duplicate answer