# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'eligibleURLPatterns' of 'Jt' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

my code is working well but always shows this error in my console.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'eligibleURLPatterns' of 'Jt' as it is undefined.
image this error

[error image include here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdcaC.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. possibly code snippet. From little I can understand you trying to do `{ eligibleURLPatterns } = Jt`  but Jt is undefined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the network tab on the chrome console e search for this `companion-bubble.js`.

It appears to be from the Loom chrome extension, disabling this extension seems to get rid of this error. I'm not sure why it happens though.
 Also see: [TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'eligibleURLPatterns' of 'Yt' as it is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075787/typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-eligibleurlpatterns-of-yt-as-it-is-nu)

Best of Luck.